# How to enable home directory encryption for a particular user?

Tags: security, encryption

I prefer to have a dedicated "administrator" user for technical purposes and that was one I've set up during installation. I've also refused to encrypt the home folder of the user.

Now, as I've added a user account for my actual work usage I want my (but not the "administrator") home folder to be encrypted.

How to turn this on?

If it is not possible then how to enable encryption for all users home directories on a system already installed?

I've found questions and answers about how to *disable* it but am not sure how to enable it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is not too late to make a new user account for your work, you could try create it as encrypted:

```
sudo adduser --encrypt-home
```

This requires the ecryptfs-utils package.

Or, you could try:

```
ecryptfs-migrate-home -u USER
```

Make sure to backup if trying the second option.

You can get the encryption key by executing:

```
ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase ~/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
```